# Visual Studio 2019 with C++17 enum reports warning C26812

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

My old code like that,

```
class A
{
public:
enum SomeType {enA=0, enB, enCount};
private:
bool SomeArray[enCount];
}
```

It works fine on Visual Studio 2017. But prompts warning [C26812](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/code-quality/c26812?view=vs-2019) on VS2019. I just modified the code followed the MS doc,

```
enum class SomeType {enA=0, enB, enCount};
```

The warning gone, but `bool SomeArray[enCount];` doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

On purpose, enum class does implicitly convert to int contrary to (old) regular enum.

You have to explicitly cast enum (to its underlying type or compatible):

```
bool SomeArray[static_cast<std::size_t>(enCount)];
```